# 2 Poisson distributions - Find probability for each

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

A road has 2 "states" each day - a busy state and a free state. Both states follows a Poisson distribution.

1. **Busy day - 120 cars** drive the road in a busy day.
2. **Free day - 80** **cars** drive the road in a free day.

The probability that **tomorrow** will have **at least 40 cars is 0.8**.
The **probability for a busy day is *p*** and the probability for a free day is ***1-p***.

Using that information, how can I **find the value of *p***?

I've tried to calculate the probability that each day will have 120 and 80 cars but couldn't do it with the given data, and doesn't seem like the right direction.

Any help would be much appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What if $100$ cars drive the road?  Is that a busy or a free day?  What if $60$ cars drive the road?  How is it that the road has only two states?

Comment: The 120 and 80 is poission speed.

Comment: That makes no sense to me.   What is "Poisson speed"?  How does it address my question?

Comment: That's the average number of cars which follows Poisson probability distribution

Comment: @Mitchell Please open a new question if you want to ask another question. And add some context and what you have done so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Let's denote $A$ as the event that tomorrow is a busy day. Then $\overline A$ is the event that tomorrow is a free day. Additionally $X$ is poisson distributed as $X\sim Poi(\lambda)$. Now apply the total law of probability. The equation becomes

$$P(X\geq 40|A)\cdot P(A)+P(X\geq 40|\overline A)\cdot P(\overline A)=0.8,$$

where $P(\overline A)=1-P(A)$

Comment: Why are you multiplying with P(A)? And I can tell that you need to use the Poission distribution function. How can I incoporate that with conditional probability?

Comment: If the event is A then the parameter is $120$. So $P(X\geq 40|A)=\sum\limits_{x=40}^{\infty} e^{-120}\cdot \frac{120^x}{x!}$

Comment: That's the probability mass function for Poisson distribution - where does the conditional probability of A plays part here?

Comment: The condition is that $\lambda=120$.

Comment: Ok, correct. And why do you need to multiply it by P(A)?

Comment: And callculus correct me if I'm wrong, but the way to calculate this would be doing 1-(P<40|A), right?

Comment: That is the law of total probability. Yes, I agree to your last comment.